# how do I access an external wireless network hard drive

Tags: networking

I could access a 1tb Buffalo-link wireless drive with my old windows 7 laptop, and put a lot of media files on it.

Recently I bought a Linux Ubuntu laptop and have tried to access it with the network button but there is no sign of it.

Comment: How exactly you connected in your windows system?

Answer (score 0):

In Nautilus go to *Files* > *Connect to server*

You can enter manually the address of the network drive by entering `smb://ipaddress/sharename`.

Comment: Whenever I do that I get an oops something went wrong message saying Unhandled error message: Failed to mount Windows share: Connection timed out

Comment: @user237644 - I get the same error when I try to reach the share when I dont have connection. Can you ping the network drive?